# c/c++ flock as mutex on linux not robust to file delete

Tags: c, linux

File locking in C using `flock` is commonly used to implement cross-platform  cooperative inter-process locking/mutex.

I have an implementation (mac/linux/win) that works well, but it is not robust to file deletion (at least under Linux).

One or more process have started creating and using lockfile (`/tmp/lockfile`) and cooperatively interlock on a shared resource with it.

Some time later, I manually delete the lockfile (`rm /tmp/lockfile`).  The running process keep on cooperating with each other, but any new process that wants to start using the same resource lock and lockfile breaks the overall mutex logic. It will  create  a new version of the `/tmp/lockfile` that is somehow different  to the one already in used in already running process.

What can be done to prevent the lockfile from being unlinked while any process has it open?
What other solutions can be used?

I can't use a semaphore because I need the lock to self-release if the owning process crashes.

Answer (score 4):

You can indeed use a semaphore. Linux provides the flag `SEM_UNDO`, which will undo the semaphore-operation on process termination (see `semop`(2)).

Comment: Thanks i'll have to give it try .

Answer (score 1):

The `rm` command does not actually delete files.  Rather, it unlinks them from the file system, as if via the `unlink(2)` syscall.  The files will not be removed from disk as long as any process holds them open (or any other hard links to them exist), and processes that *do* hold them open continue to refer to the same file, even though it no longer appears in directory listings.  Nothing prevents another file from being created and linked to the file system at the same place as the previous one, but that is an altogether different file.  This behavior is desirable for consistent program behavior, and some programs intentionally use it to their advantage for managing temporary files.

There is nothing you can do to prevent a process *with sufficient privileges* from unlinking the lock file.  Any process that has sufficient privilege to create the lock file has sufficient privilege to unlink it, with the consequences you describe.  One usually mitigates this problem by creating a temporary file with an unpredictable name for use with `flock()`, so that the file name or an open file handle must be exchanged between processes that want to synchronize actions by locking that file.  For the particular case of child processes, you can rely on the child inheriting open file descriptors from its parent to enable them to get at the lock file even if it has been unlinked.

On the other hand, if you are relying on a lock file with a well-known name then the solution may be to create the file in advance, make root its owner and the owner of every directory in the path of hard links leading to it, and deny all other users write access the file and the directories.  You could consider further wrapping it up with mandatory access controls (SELinux policy) if you wanted to be even more careful.

Comment: the lock file name  is actually well know and unique,

Comment: @MichelSanches, then your options for protecting the lock file are the same ones available for protecting any file.  My answer already provides a recommendation for that case.  A process holding the file open confers no protection against unlinking, regardless of `flock()`ing.  This is by design.

Comment: Yes your right  i used  /tmp/xxx as  a know good place where any user can have access to and create a file. Just tough of a scenario where root or any user decide to clean /tmp because space is needed and brake my mutex logic :(  Creating file as root with precise attribute is a good idea  but will it work ? It seam flock fail if you have no write "permisision". Also giving file root priviliged make the installation process a bit more complex and need root privileged. Still Many thanks for the suggestion i'll have to try it.

Comment: @MichelSanches, if the lock file is not writable by your process, then you must open it with mode `O_RDONLY`, and you must not include `O_EXCL` among the open flags.  It is not useful to include `O_CREAT`, but neither is it directly harmful.  As long as you successfully open the file, you should be able to `flock()` it.  I just tested this to be sure.

Comment: i tested open root owned file  with "rw-r-r"  , open rd only  is ok of course but lockf is not it fail :(

Comment: @MichelSanches, what does `lockf()` have to do with anything?  You said you are using `flock()`.

Comment: @MichelSanches, on Linux, `lockf()` is implemented on top of `fcntl()` locks.  The only exclusive locks provided by `fcntl()` are write locks, and you can take out such a lock only on a file open for writing.  Linux (and BSD) `flock()` is an entirely separate system.  FWIW, OS X is a fork of BSD.

Comment: oops my mistake i  used lockf so far  (mac os and linux). I started with that for some reason i can't remenber. I can change but will it make any difference on the end ?

Comment: @MichelSanches, as I said, `lockf()`/`fcntl()` locks and `flock()` locks are completely separate and independent on Linux and BSD.  They are both advisory locks, but they have somewhat different semantics.  Among the differences, `flock()` can provide exclusive locks on read-only files, but `fcntl()` cannot.  I cannot say whether any of the other differences would be significant for you.